# Expiry date in TestFlight distribution of app

Tags: ios, app-store, testflight

I joined apple developer program in feb. 2017. For my app testflight is showing expiry date as 17 Aug. 2017 so what exactly it is? How and when I will review to keep my testing continue for same app?

Please provide steps as well to review it.

[image: Image of testflight notification for my app]

Answer (score 6):

You can get more info form [Resources & Help](https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/apps/faq/TestFlight%20Beta%20Testing_Overview) section form iTunes

**How long can a user test a beta build?**

> Users can test a beta build for up to **90 days** from the day you upload
>   your build to iTunes Connect and it finishes processing. You can see
>   the remaining days for your test in the builds section under
>   TestFlight.

To continue testing your app after 90 days have passed, **upload a new build**.

After expiration your test won't be able download or run your app.If once your build is expired then you have to upload new build for continue testing you app.

[Apple Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/release-notes/) says

> You can now distribute and test multiple builds at the same time. The
>   build expiration countdown begins from the time the build is uploaded,
>   rather than the first time a build is sent to an external tester. The
>   build expiration limit has been increased to 90 days...,etc